# Understanding Independence as measure specific

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

I'm trying to understand the definition of independent events or sets in a sigma algebra on a probability space to be something determined by the probability measure the space is endowed with. However, I have been unable to come up with a good enough example to illustrate this to myself.

For example, would it be possible to have three events $A, B, C$ such that when considered with respect to probability measure $\mu, C$ is independent of $A$ and $C$ independent of $B$ but $C$ *not independent* of $A \cup B$? However, when considered with respect to some alternative probability measure $\nu$, could we have a situation where each of the events $A$, $B$ and $C$ has strictly positive probability with $\nu$ but are mutually independent?